# Laravel Update multiple rows using multiple select menu inputs

Tags: laravel, select, menu

What I want to accomplish, is to update multiple rows at once, based on what has been submitted using the form. I have a form with multiple checkboxes and select menu's, using:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]">
<select name="numbers[]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
...and so on
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
$checkedIDs         = Input::get('checkbox');
$selectedNumbers    = Input::get('numbers');

if(is_array($checkedIDs))
{
    Products::whereIn('id',$checkedIDs)->update(['checkbox' => '1']);
    Products::whereIn('id', $checkedIDs)->update(array('number' => '?'));
}
```

In the above code, how do I go about updating the "number" column to the actual submitted "number" in the checkboxes? If I change the question mark to for example "5", all checked checkboxes in the form will get their number updated to "5" in the database. But ofcourse, it needs to be selected value from the select menus, which differ for each checkbox.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a foreach loop?

Comment: I think it can be done without using one, not? If not, I'll have to go with a foreach loop ofcourse :)

Comment: Yes I think you're right the update method accepts an array so it is possible. You need to see how your data is coming through and if it's coming through in a way that the update method will accept it.

Comment: That's basically all I needed to know thanks. Now I just have to make sure the array is passed in the right way because I think that is the issue with my code. I will check it and see if I can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I believe it expects key and value the key being the field it updates in the table in your db. But unsure. Hope you can find the solution. Haven't been on my pc so can't check this out fully.

Comment: I'm almost there I think. I will edit my original post to show what I have right now.